# Does our application always use the latest installed .NET 4.6.x, even if its targeted to and ships with .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net

I have searched google and various Windows articles, but due to some inconsistencies I'd very much appreciate if someone could ensure my findings.

Our application is targeted to use .NET 4.5. Our client encountered a bug that MS says is fixed in 4.6.2. We cannot reproduce the bug ourselves, but apparently its there.

The question is, if I install 4.6.2 on my developer computer and build the application (still targeted to 4.5), will it then use that 4.6.2 in the debugger and when I run the release build? So I would effectively be testing it with 4.6.2 all the time.

I understand I can have many targeting packs / reference assemblies for VS installed, but apparently these don't contain any actual implementation code, so I gather it'll always use the installed run time version? And apparently one can have multiple major versions of the .net run time installed, but 4.6.x installations seem to replace 4.5, and will therefore be used instead?

Comment: The .NET 4.6 *runtime* is a binary replacement for any version after 4.x. So your application runs on the 4.6.2 runtime even if it targets 4.5. BTW the earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.**2**, which adds support for TLS1.2. You should target a newer version than 4.5.2 anyway

Comment: See also [Does .NET 4.6.1 make .NET 4.0 redundant?](https://superuser.com/q/1101383/24082) on Super User.

Comment: So yes, 4.6.2 replaces 4.6.1 which replaces 4.6.0 which replaces 4.5.x. Only the latest version counts. The targeted framework is just limiting your feature set, so if you depend on behavior that is working in your later version but was buggy in an earlier version, it’s possible that that code will break if executed under that earlier version.

Comment: Ok, thank you the clarifications!